# Crop UIImage from a transformed UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, crop

I am letting the user capture an image from the camera or picking one from the library.
This image I display in an `UIImageView`.
The user can now scale and position the image within a bounding box, exactly like you would do using the `UIImagePickerController` when `allowsEditing` is set to `YES`.

When the user is satisfied with the result and taps Done I would like to produce a cropped `UIImage`.
The problem arises when using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` as this does not take the scaling into account. The transform is applied to the imageView like this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imageView.transform, newScale, newScale);
[self.imageView setTransform:transform];
```

Using a gestureRecognizer.

I assume what is happening is; the UIImageView is scaled and moved, it then applies the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit to the UIImage is holds and when I ask it to crop the image, it does exactly that - whit no regards to the scaling positioning. The reason I think this, is that if I don't scale or move the image but just tap Done straight away the cropping works.

I crop the image like this:

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage*) img toRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

    if (scale>1.0) {        
        rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x*scale , rect.origin.y*scale, rect.size.width*scale, rect.size.height*scale);        
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.imageView.image.scale orientation:self.imageView.image.imageOrientation];
    //    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

Passing in a cropRect from a view that is a subView of my main view (the square overlay box, like in UIImagePickerController). Main UIView has a UIImageView that gets scaled and a UIView that displays the crop rectangle.

How can I get the "what you see is what you get" cropping and which factors must I take into account. Or maybe suggestions if I should implemented the hierarchy or scaling differently.

Comment: I stack in the same problem , you have a solution ?

Comment: Any resolution to this? Have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple trick. Apple has got samples on its site to show how to zoom into a photo using code. Once done zooming, using graphic context take the frame size of the bounding view, and take the image with that. Eg Uiview contains scroll view which has the zoomed image. So the scrollview zooms and so does your image, now take the frame size of your bounding UIview, and create an image context out of it and then save that as a new image. Tell me if that makes sense.

Cheers :)

Comment: Hi Sam thanks. I am trying to reconstruct your suggestion in my head - I display the full image but only wish to crop the "preview" square I overlaid on the image. Using the scrollView approach will I not just get the same problem, but with other views? i.e. I will still have to place the image in a UIImageView that I then add to the scrollView - but the bounding crop box is not in the scrollView as I want it to be static when the user moves/scales the image. Thx.